# How to transfer files from BlueStacks to another BlueStacks on different PC?

Tags: file-transfer, bluestacks

I have been playing a game called Star Wars: Commander and I got a new laptop, and I thought BlueStacks would transfer my file to my new laptop from my old laptop and it didn't. I really don't want to start over. Could someone tell me how to transfer my data to my new laptop?

Comment: Could you clarify some things: Do you want to transfer general files, migrate data from 1 app, or migrate *all* data?

Comment: migrate data from 1 app